# Why Nextjs Link scroll to top not working, when I change route

Tags: next.js, next-link

I am using next/link, but when I change the route, scroll to top not working.

```
<Link href="/some-page" scroll={false}> Go</Link>
```

What I should do?
I try too much methods and I did not have result.

Answer (score 6):

You can create this component and import it on the page where you want to scroll to the top.

If you're using a version older than NextJS 13, then just remove the "use client";.

```
// scrollToTop
"use client";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import React from "react";

export default function scrollToTop() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);
  return null;
}
```

Import it on the page where you want to scroll to the top:

```
// examplePage
import React from "react";
import ScrollToTop from "./scrollToTop"; // imported scroll to top

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <div>Text...</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Now whenever you enter or refresh the page, it will always scroll to the top.

Comment: good workaround, however  there is no need to add this extra code since we have the same behaviour with Link in Nextjs the scroll props is set to true by default, we can even manually set it.

Comment: Still useful when we use router in the client component, thanks for the sharing

Comment: @ShueiYang For some reason that I can't fathom, the scroll props don't always work with dynamic routes. This does. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is disabling the scroll to top by using `scroll={false}`

via the documentation:

> The default behavior of Link is to scroll to the top of the page. When there is a hash defined it will scroll to the specific id, like a normal  tag. To prevent scrolling to the top / hash scroll={false} can be added to Link:

Remove the `scroll={false}` to resolve.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried without scroll={false}, but did not work

Comment: Please provide a MRE so it can be further troubleshooted https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - you can additionally use stackblitz or codesandbox to show what is happening

Answer (score 2):

So,I solved the problem with this way:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
export default function ToTop(){
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(()=>{
      const handleRouteChange = () => {
          document.getElementById('top').scrollIntoView();
    }
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
    },[]);

    return ('');
}
```

but I did not like it

Answer (score 1):

Add this to next.config.js and every link you click will start from top page.

```
const nextConfig = {
  ...
  trailingSlash: true,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i had [shallow prop](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#shallow) on my link which allows you to change the URL without running data fetching methods again

Before:

```
<Link
    key={i}
    href={``}
    shallow    //<-- remove this         
>
  ...
</Link>
```

after:

```
<Link
        key={i}
        href={``}                     
>
      ...
</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// scrollToTop
"use client";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import React from "react";

export default function scrollToTop() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);
  return null;
}
```

**Nextjs App Router**

```
// loading.tsx
// only imported once.

export default function Loading() {
   return <ScrollToTop />
}
```